# Is it possible to extract preprocessor information from clang's parse tree?

Tags: c++, parsing, serialization, clang, c-preprocessor

Consider the following simple header, demo.h:

```
#define PERSIST
struct Serialised
{
    int someTransientValue ;
    PERSIST int aNumberToPersist ;
};
```

I use the following code and Clang's python API to iterate over the header:

```
import sys, clang.cindex
def callexpr_visitor(node, parent, userdata):
    if node.location.file: print node.location.file, node.displayname, node.kind
    return 2
tu = clang.cindex.Index.create().parse(sys.argv[1], args=['-x', 'c++'])
clang.cindex.Cursor_visit(tu.cursor, clang.cindex.Cursor_visit_callback(callexpr_visitor), None)
```

This prints out the elements of Clang's AST, producing the following output:

> demo.h Serialised CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL
>       demo.h someTransientValue CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
>       demo.h aNumberToPersist CursorKind.FIELD_DECL

Does anyone know how I can extract the preprocessor declaration associated with the member variable called 'aNumberToPersist'?, is there a better way to 'tag' variables in a manner that manifests clearly in the parse tree?

Xubuntu 12.04, clang version 3.1 (tags/RELEASE_31/final), Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix.

Comment: Just in case you are not notified of changes to the answers (I can never remember), from today on Clang's trunk version will retain all parsed attributes thanks to a commit by [Michael Han](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=165082).

Comment: Excellent!, thanks for remembering :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably say: not this way.

Macros are not represented in the AST per se. Types, Attributes, etc... all those elements that have *semantic* values are represented (and comments), and optionally you can query whether some of them were expanded from a macro and get back that original macro spelling; however macros in themselves do not appear in the AST, at all.

If you could, it might be more interesting to *extend* Clang with a new **attribute**, especially in C++11: `[[gearoid::persist]]`. C++11 requires that compilers ignore attributes they know not about, so by "namespacing" your own attributes you pretty much guarantee that only you will care about their meaning.

I know not, unfortunately, whether you will need to teach Clang about your attributes so they are represented in the AST ([Michael Han](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-October/024637.html) is working on always memorizing them). In any case, you may get more useful answers on the [Clang DEV](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) mailing list (unfortunately, there is no Clang Users mailing list).

**EDIT**: Just [landed today](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=165082)! Clang will now retain all attributes (even those it does not understand) in its AST.

Comment: According to [clang's status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) generalized attributes are not, yet, implemented by clang.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I must admit I do not know whether this means that the trunk version of Clang will reject unknown attributes or whether Clang is not able to parse attributes in all the positions this proposal meant to insert them.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thankfully, it looks like [Michael Han](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-October/024637.html) is working on this. Apparently Clang needs to progress on both fronts: unknown attributes are dropped on the floor and attributes are not allowed everywhere they could be.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Michael's work [landed today](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=165082), attributes are now parsed (though ignored). I don't think it fully covers all the possible places they can appear, but it's definitely a good start.

Comment: While very interesting news, I suspect this answer is ambiguous; to me, it suggested that all C++11 attributes are kept in the AST, regardless of whether they are recognized by clang or not, that is, even if they trigger an "unknown attribute 'xxx' ignored" warning. However, some experiments indicate that this is not the case. I have therefore asked a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20180917/395370) that I hope may clarify the issue. (I chose not to append to this discussion, as the original question deals with macros, not attributes.)

Comment: @jorgen: I would expect them to be there (that was and is my understanding), hope someone will be in a position to clarify.

Comment: Are you sure this ever went through?  I'm running 3.8 on `class [[randomthing]] Foo {};` and I get ` warning: unknown attribute 'randomthing' ignored ` but in my AST I see no reference to it, but I do see my class.  If I change the attribute to "deprecated" I do see the attribute in the -ast-dump output.

Comment: @xaxxon: I expect that it did, however since I didn't follow up in the last 4 years...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I posted to clang frontend users.   if I get a response I'll post more info here.

Comment: @xaxxon: Great, don't hesitate to make an answer of it!